# How to add ng-app to html element without access to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working inside of a template system and trying to use Angular.js. I need to add ng-app to html element but do not have access to do this directly on page. So basically my page starts of like this:

```
<html>
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
<html ng-app>
```

I do have access to add javascript to page.

Is there a way to add javascript to tell the page to change

```
<html> to <html ng-app>
```

Comment: Could you not add the ng-app to a div that is inside your template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually initialize angular, as seen in the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap):

```
 /* in your js file */
 angular.element(document).ready(function() {
     angular.module('myApp', []);
     angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
 });
```

Comment: Praise the lord. I am going to name my next child Beterraba.

Comment: I did the same.  Little Beterraba Jr is now 2 years old and has just started speaking.  His first word was "transclusion"!

Answer (score 1):

Beterraba's answer is spot on.

I also noticed you can define modules outside of the manual bootstrap.  I.e. all you need inside of the manual initialize is angular.bootstrap...

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() { angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']); });

var app = angular.module("myApp", ["module1", "module2"]);
app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  ....
}
```

...works perfectly.